# Replace occurences of string corresponding to a regex

Tags: php, regex

I have the following strings:

```
$a = "test1";
$b = "test&nbsp;2";
$c = "test&lt;3";
$d = "test&4";
```

I would like to replace occurrences of "&" followed by some letters and terminate by a ";".

The output should be :

```
$a = "test1";
$b = "test 2";
$c = "test 3";
$d = "test&4";
```

How can I do that with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$x = preg_replace('/&[a-z]+;/', ' ', $b);
echo $x;
```

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, you don't need a regex, most likely what you need is to decode the HTML entities, and that can be done with [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php), as in:

```
$a = html_entity_decode("test1");
$b = html_entity_decode("test&nbsp;2");
$c = html_entity_decode("test&lt;3");
$d = html_entity_decode("test&4");

var_dump($a,$b,$c,$d);
```

Comment: This solution returns `"test<3"`, while OP needs `"test 3"`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @this.lau_ is the best, but if you want the regexp, try this

```
(\&)([a-z]{1,4})(;)
```